# Strange CardView behaviour

Tags: android, android-cardview

I'm trying to implement simple cardview with semi-transparent background.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="#33FFFFFF"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        android:foreground="#33FFFFFF"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp">
......
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

And this is the result in L and preL

android L: (Nexus 5)
[image]

Pre L:

[image]

Any idea how to fix the pre L to look like L ?
As you can see there are too many borders/strokes surrounding the card.
I'm can guess it relates to shadows and stuff...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like it's a known defect in [google forums](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=78061)

Thanks to @benhylau for providing implementation for cardview with alpha [here](http://github.com/BerlinMeshnet/cjdns-android/pull/21)

There no possible to color cardview background with #__FFFFF as it ignores the transparency values. need to work with alpha attribute

Comment: Yes, set it in the Java. Like here: https://github.com/BerlinMeshnet/cjdns-android/pull/21
https://github.com/BerlinMeshnet/cjdns-android/pull/21/files#diff-242658fb5c71623f8e6c0c02f8650df2R242